# Frequency count of keywords/phrases stores in excel on a word doc

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm mostly a VBA rookie, but I'm trying to determine if it's possible to search a word doc for a pre-defined list of keywords/phrases (meaning some strings with spaces) stored in a separate excel file, and then output a frequency count of the found keywords/phrases into a new document.

So, for example, if the first row of my excel file had the word/phrases, it would search and output a document with 2 columns, word/phrase on the left, and number of occurrences on the right. That specific format isn't really important, but that would be the general idea.

Comment: What is said below would work. I would use a scripting dictionary to handle the frequency portion though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You could:

- Write some Excel VBA to pick up the keywords/phrases and put them into an array
- From Excel VBA open the word file
- From Excel VBA get the document.content.text into a string
- Then loop through each item in the array, checking against the string.
- Outputting the results into a new document as you go

I am not going to do it for you, but if you have more specific questions about each part as you go along doing it, I would be happy to help more.